# Are there any downsides of using single quotes around integer values when querying int fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

Beside the point of not doing it, is there any harm in writing a query like this:

```
select * from table where id = '14192668838072324' order by id desc
```

instead of this:

```
select * from table where id = 14192668838072324 order by id desc
```

? (id is an integer field)

Comment: In my 2 decades of web development, I haven't encountered any issues with putting it into quotes.

Comment: Why would you want to, though? If you are hand-writing queries, that's two keystrokes you can save. If you are accessing DB programmatically, then you should be using prepared statements, and leave quoting to the professionals — I mean, the DB driver: your query should be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?`, without quotes. (For the reasoning, I will let [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) explain.)

Comment: I believe that if you read it as a int as oppose to a nvarchar it is better on the lookup because computers read ints a lot faster than Nvarchars due to not having to look through every char but the int as a whole

Comment: @Ultimater: until you use a different DBMS that is more strict about proper data types and e.g. won't use an index on an integer column if you compare it to a string.

Comment: For security reasons, SQL injection for example, you should not use quotes for an integer. Doing that you add extra job for Mysql to convert string to integer With all errors case we can imagine.

Comment: @Amadan I’m using Laravel Livewire and it’s having difficulties with JS and large ints, but if I cast the id to string on the model I don’t have to worry about it. I know it’s kind of backwards to fix a JS downfall on the server side, but if it’s not an issue it’s a very easy solution to my problem :)

Comment: None of that has anything to do with writing quotes in queries. If you are using Laravel, your query should look like `Table::where('id', $value)->get()`, and it should just work assuming your models are configured correctly, Laravel should figure out if it needs to quote or not — raw SQL should not be needed unless you're doing something very complex. Also, while integers are limited in JavaScript, big integers are not, unless you are supporting ancient browsers. In JS, `14192668838072324` might give you trouble, but `14192668838072324n` should not.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the answer! When using Livewire, the sending of data back and forth is kind of automatic and I ran into the JS max int limit. The solution I got from the Livewire community was to cast the int to string before it hit the browser, but this is kind of cumbersome to do manually everywhere and easy to miss, especially on a team. I guess you could make an observer or what not, but just putting `protected $casts = ['id' => 'string'];` on the model took care of this everywhere.

Comment: Again, it's probably not an ideal solution for a frontend problem and I'll try to look for a different way to do it, but when I checked the Laravel Debugbar I noticed that the generated query had '' when the id was casted as string, which of course makes sense. Maybe I could look into mutators on the model or in Livewire instead to cast back to int, but it's definitely a more involved solution. Let me know if you have any ideas :)